# Foreign Key '... ' references invalid column '...' in referencing table '... '. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, alter-table

I want to add a column to 'Customer' table which is FOREIGN KEY REFERENCING 'Test_Drive' table. I am using

```
ALTER TABLE Customer
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Test_Drive_ID) REFERENCES Test_Drive(Test_Drive_ID);
```

I think it should work properly on my tables. Below I send the Designs of them:

[image: Customer Table]

[image: Test_Drive Table]

I have no idea if I am blind, and do some spelling mistake, or something's wrong. I am grateful for any help :)

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 98
> Foreign key 'Test_Drive_ID' references invalid column 'Test_Drive_ID' in referencing table 'Customer'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 98
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to add *a column*, along with the corresponding foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer
    ADD Test_Drive_ID INT
    REFERENCES Test_Drive(Test_Drive_ID);
```

If you want to assign an explicit name to the FK:

```
ALTER TABLE Customer
    ADD Test_Drive_ID INT
    CONSTRAINT FK_Customer_Test_Drive 
        FOREIGN KEY (Test_Drive_ID) 
        REFERENCES Test_Drive(Test_Drive_ID)
;
```